# How do tsql query in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

in sql i have query

```
select * from table where id in (5,7,8)
```

How do this in LINQ query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var t = from u in table
               where new[] { 5, 7, 8 }.Contains(u.id)
               select u
```

Comment: I was reviewing and came to this post and was curious to know the solution for a case where this 5,7,8 comes from an array dynamically filled in by some control or an event on a page.

Answer (score 3):

```
var ids = new int[] { 5, 7, 8 };
var rows = from row in table 
           where ids.Contains(row.id) 
           select row
```